# angular 4 module for here-API

Tags: angular, here-api

I am unable to find angular-4 module for Here-Api. They have given only JS SDK which is difficult to integrate in angular-4. Has anyone able to integrate HERE-API js/API SDK for angular-4?

Comment: HERE Maps for JavaScript library does not depend on a particular framework. What were the obstacles you encountered when using it in an Angular application?

Comment: how do i install it?  im not able to call the Here map in typescript?

Comment: Another Angular module which has been created is https://github.com/mjaric/ng2-heremaps

Answer (score 3):

first include all script tags in the index page
then install the definitions file from [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/)

```
npm install --save @types/heremaps
```

then add a reference tag `/// <reference types="@types/heremaps" />`
so you have all the typings and intellisense

```
 var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'app_id': 'YOUR APP ID',
        'app_code': 'YOUR_APP_CODE'
    });
```

Comment: just this ? how do you call the function? and declaration at app.modules.ts how is that done?

Answer (score 2):

As there is no npm package for HERE maps, you'd need to integrate the HERE library directly in your index.html header, as in the examples from the [developer portal](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html), or in the *scripts* array property of `.angular-cli.json`.

Once the scripts are loaded, you can start to integrate the maps in your angular components. Besides applying HERE examples, the only thing you need to know is how to reference to the HTML element of your angular component that will host the map.

I put up a project on github with all the required setup, that you can checkout, `npm install` and then `npm start` : **https://github.com/michaelbazos/angular-here**

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit older now, but I've actually written a tutorial of using HERE with Angular.

https://developer.here.com/blog/display-here-maps-angular-web-application

Long story short, you add the HERE JavaScript libraries to your index.html file, declare the platform class, and then you're good. Of course my tutorial will have a lot more depth.

Just for clarity, I work for HERE on the Developer Evangelism team.

Best,

Comment: This is incomplete, I get a new error just with the basic code: `ERROR ReferenceError: H is not defined
    at MapResultsHereComponent.ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 0):

**Option (a):** You can use imports in your `My-App.ts` file: e.g.

```
//In My-Map-App.ts
import "src/assets/here/mapsjs-core.js";
import "src/assets/here/mapsjs-service.js";
import "src/assets/here/mapsjs-places.js";
declare let H;

// then some use case..
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyMapApp {

  searchForPlaces(){
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({ ... });
    var explore = new H.places.Explore( ... );
  }
}
```

Above, I have downloaded and copied the here JS files into my local assets directory.

---

**Option (b):** is to use a `<script..>` import in `index.html` and then **`declare let H`** in your `.ts` file.

---

> **FWIW:** as my mapping application has expanded, I find putting the **`map`** object into an Angular `service` and letting Angular's inversion of control insert it into my other `components` and `services` is the path of least adversity.